# SSRS Report show all tables in one Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Creating the SSRS report for First time and i wanted to show my Report as below image, I have a Task table and related product, equipment table , how do i create report to show all tables in one report like Image. 
Created a separate dataset for each table with parameter 'taskID'

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Creating three tablixes onto the design surface and then connecting each to a dataset will create results very similar to what you want. If you've tried that, what don't you like about those results?

Comment: Jamie F Thanks, i am pretty new to creating report. so, i am not sure how do i connect each dataset. As of now i have 3 rdl file for 3 datasets

Comment: Simply drag a field from a dataset to a tablix. The first field dragged into a tablix will connect the tablix to that dataset. (It is probably worth your time to look through a tutorial like this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167305(v=sql.100).aspx )

Comment: Thanks Jamie F, I am able achieve what i need.